# Python script to run only in a time window

Tags: python

how should the code look so the below script runs only between 06.30h and 8.00h??
best regards

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from time import strftime    
import sys    
import subprocess from subprocess    
import Popen    
import pifacedigitalio    
from time import sleep


pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital() # creates a PiFace Digital 
object testprocess = None

while strftime('%H:%M') >= '06:29':
    while(True):
        sleep(0.1)
        if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscript"])
            testprocess = Popen(["/bin/myscript1"])
            if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 0:
                if testprocess:
                    testprocess.kill()
                    testprocess = None
                    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/mycript"])
            sleep(1)
            if strftime('%H:%M') == '08:00':
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: Any reason not to use a system capability (e.g. cron, Task Schedular) to run the script at the appropriate time - that is what they are designed for.

Comment: Have you tried *nothing* yourself?

Comment: correct like this above??

Comment: @ Nenad, I put your code in, but when input is hi and the time window is not correct  the testprocess = Popen(["/bin/myscript1"]) is still be executed. Could you please have I look in post 0 if the code is coorect like this??

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with something like this:

```
from time import strftime
import sys
while strftime('%H:%M') >= '18:00':
    #Your code
    if strftime('%H:%M') == '20:30':
         sys.exit()
```

You can learn more about time module here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score 0):

just get time into a time struct and compute the number of minutes from midnight, test the time window in minutes:

```
lt = time.localtime()
minutes = 60*lt.tm_hour + lt.tm_min
if 60*6+30 <= minutes <= 60*8:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscript"])
    testprocess = Popen(["/bin/myscript1"])
```